# Fisher information for a posterior distribution MCMC

Tags: python, mcmc

The method I am using requires me to calculate the Fisher Information for a the posterior distribution (with respect to all hyperparameters). What I have at the moment is a Monte Carlo sample from the posterior distribution. I feel I can use and approximate these by sample mean and covariance of second and first derivatives respectively but I am looking for a more efficient way.

However, it was suggested to me to use `optim(..., Hessian=TRUE)` however I do not see how an optimisation routine could help.